Is there a way to reverse order in a union type?
Typically, union type order doesn't matter. But for a typing like
type A = { isFoo: true, foo: number }
type B = { isBar: true, bar: number }
type C = [A] | [B] | [A & B]
type D = [A & B] | [B] | [A]

the order matters because the error message on invalid type will be quite different for type C and type D.
For instance,
const c: C = [{ isFoo: true, foo: 1, isBar:true }]

will have error message of Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'isBar' does not exist in type 'A'.
but
const d: D = [{ isFoo: true, foo: 1, isBar:true }]

will have ts error of Property 'bar' is missing in type '{ isFoo: true; foo: number; isBar: true; }' but required in type 'B' which is more user friendly.
(Try on the playground)
I have tried some options like
type Reverse<T, R = never, O = T> = [T] extends [never] ? R : T extends infer U ? Reverse<Exclude<O, U>, U | R> : never;

type E = Reverse<C>

but the type of E is still in the same order as C.
I am at a loss if this is possible at all.

You can't control union order. There are awful tricks to make a particular order more likely, but TypeScript caches unions and reuses them, so if you have type X = A | B; type Y = B | A , TypeScript will use the same order for both of them see playground link. See this comment on ms/TS#13298. What you're trying to do is impossible. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer (showing the awful tricks) or find a suitable duplication source. If not, what am I missing?

I dont think there is a straight forward way to reverse union types directly in TS. But there are definitely workaround
using helper types and type gaurds
type A = { isFoo: true, foo: number }
type B = { isBar: true, bar: number }
type AB = A & B;

function isA(value: any): value is A {
    return value.isFoo === true;
}

function isB(value: any): value is B {
    return value.isBar === true;
}

function isAB(value: any): value is AB {
    return isA(value) && isB(value);
}

type D = [AB] | [B] | [A];

const d: D = [{ isFoo: true, foo: 1, isBar: true }];


or for a better control over error messages:
function assertType<T>(value: T): asserts value is T {}

type A = { isFoo: true, foo: number }
type B = { isBar: true, bar: number }
type AB = A & B;

type D = [AB] | [B] | [A];

function validateD(value: any): asserts value is D {
    if (isAB(value[0])) {
        return;
    } else if (isB(value[0])) {
        return;
    } else if (isA(value[0])) {
        return;
    }
    throw new Error("invalid type for D");
}

const d = [{ isFoo: true, foo: 1, isBar: true }];
validateD(d); //throw a custom error if the type does not match

